# rdlc report showing empty data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rdlc

I need to display some data to my rdlc report , but it is showing nothing even though my data table has item.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = new clsDBFN().rpt_GetData(); //Call to return data from data base


        _reportViewer.Reset();
        _reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        ReportDataSource reportDSDetail = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

        _reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "rptData.rdlc";
        _reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDSDetail);
        _reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        _reportViewer.Visible = true;
        this._reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

I reference http://tutorialhouse.weebly.com/reporting from here , but i have to idea why it is not working

Comment: Are there any error messages in Output window in VS?

Comment: @InitKnit no error , can build can run , just report no data